# Apk does not work after signing it with Apk Easy tool ?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, decompiling

I am using Unity, I finished my little game ( just one scene ) and build my apk and tested it on my phone ( android application ), and it worked, but I wanted to sign it with Apk Easy Tool so I decompiled my apk, recompile it and sign it but When I test it, it works fine in emulator, but I get a message when I test it on my phone, a message pops us telling that the Application can not be installed because the package semms corrupted.

I hope I can get some help, because I am stuck and can not find a solution.

Any Help would me much appreciated.

Comment: Did you uninstall the version that was already on your phone?

Comment: TheWanderer : Yes I did.

Comment: Unity can sign you apk itself. You can set it up in the Player Settings under Publishing Settings.

Comment: JeanLuc : Well I did, But I wanted to re sign it with this program in an other PC .. but that problem appeared .. what can caue such problem ?

Comment: But why take the complicated way? Do you want to change something in the apk? Did you lose your unity project?